# Sign of Wave Number and Angular Frequency

Tags: waves, solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons

In chapter 9, page 78, of The Oxford Solid State Physics Basics by Steven Simon, the author claims an ansatz given by $$e^{iwt-ikna}$$ as a solution of 1D monatomic chain  of atoms connected by springs. The book states the following without explaining why:
"Since we are taking the real part, it is sufficient to consider only ω $\geqslant $ 0,
however, we must be careful that k can then have either sign and these
are inequivalent once we have specified that ω is positive."

Why would specifying ω require us to have k be negative and positive and why negative and positive signs of k would be inequivalent even though from the dispersion relation they give the same ω as it is symmetric with k? Also if we choose ω to be negative and positive as well, will there be any restrictions on the values of k?

Comment: One corresponds to right-moving waves and the other to left-moving waves.  So there each state (except for $k=0$) is doubly-degenerate (as you noticed).

Comment: The author seems to suggest I can choose a negative frequency. not sure if that makes sense but what would happen to the k values will they be only positive in this case?